# Changing a game objects velocity on button press in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to add a dash mechanic to a game character im building. However for some reason i can't get the game objects velocity to actually change. I tried using addForce which worked, but i had to add a lot in order to get the desired effect and that behaved strangely sometimes!

Do i need to do anything else to the game objects velocity than i already doing?

Heres my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float dashSpeed;
    private int dashDirection;
    private float dashCoolDown;
    public float startDashCoolDown;
    private float dashTime;
    public float startDashTime;
    public GameObject dashEffect;

    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    private float moveInput;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    private Animator anim;
    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private int extraJumps;
    public int extraJumpsValue;

    public GameObject dustEffect;
    public GameObject trailEffect;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Setting up references.
        isGrounded = transform.Find("GroundCheck");
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        dashTime = startDashTime;
        dashCoolDown = startDashCoolDown;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        isGrounded = false;

        // Check to see if grounded
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
            {
                isGrounded = true;
                anim.SetBool("Ground", isGrounded);
            }
        }

        // Check if movement is allowed
        if (!GameMaster.disableMovement)
        {
            // Move character
            moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            Instantiate(trailEffect, groundCheck.position, Quaternion.identity);
            anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(moveInput));
        }

        // Flip character
        if (isFacingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (isFacingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Check if the player is grounded
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
        }

        // Check if movement is allowed
        if (!GameMaster.disableMovement)
        {

            // Check for jump
            // If the player has more than one jump available
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0)
            {
                isGrounded = false;
                anim.SetBool("Ground", isGrounded);
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
                extraJumps--;
                Instantiate(dustEffect, groundCheck.position, Quaternion.identity);
            }

            // If the player only has one jump available
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
            {
                isGrounded = false;
                anim.SetBool("Ground", isGrounded);
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            }

            // Check for dash
            if (dashCoolDown <= 0)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    anim.SetBool("Dash", true);
                    Dash();
                    dashTime = startDashTime;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dashCoolDown -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

    }

    void Dash()
    {
        if (dashTime <= 0)
        {
            dashCoolDown = startDashCoolDown;
            anim.SetBool("Dash", false);
        }
        else
        {
            dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (isFacingRight)
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector2.right * dashSpeed;
            }
            else if (!isFacingRight)
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector2.left * dashSpeed;
            }
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did it behave strangely? Also, which button press are you referring to? I see two possible button presses.

Comment: Left shift for the dash.

Well depending on what i hit, or if i was in the air it would fling my game object really far

Comment: You know that this `dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;` in `Dash` is called exactly **once** since `Dash` is not called repeatedly, right? And for the same reason `dashCoolDown = startDashCoolDown;
            anim.SetBool("Dash", false);` might never get called

Answer (score 0):

If you dont get the desired dash effect with Rigidbody.velocity, you can try using Rigidbody.addForce(). I know you said you already used it, but there are multiple different force modes you can apply here. I would suggest using this one, because it applies full force from the start and then drops it off. You can read more about it yourself [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.VelocityChange.html).

So you could modify your code like so:

```
void Dash()
    {
        if (isFacingRight)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.right*dashSpeed,  ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        else if (!isFacingRight)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.left*dashSpeed,  ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
```

Note, that you also dont need to call dash repeatedly to falloff the velocity. this function should now be only called onse the button to dash (shift) has been pressed.

Hope this helped!